# ¿Cómo puedo proteger rutas con react router dom v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

¿Cómo puedo proteger rutas con la libreria react router dom v6?
Estoy creando mi primera app en react y me gustaria saber como puedo proteger determinadas rutas, en este caso todas las rutas que se encuentren en `/dashboard/` en esta área solo podran ingresar usuarios que tengan credenciales, es decir que se encuentren registrados.

### Públicas (cualquier persona puede ver estas páginas)

- http://localhost:3000/
- http://localhost:3000/register
- http://localhost:3000/login

### Privadas (cuando el usuario inicia sesión):

- http://localhost:3000/dashboard/
- http://localhost:3000/dashboard/accounting
- http://localhost:3000/dashboard/employee
- http://localhost:3000/dashboard/ecommerce

#### package.json

```
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.1",
```

#### Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

#### App.js

```
import AppRouter from "./routers/AppRouter";
import "./css/main.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <AppRouter />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### AppRouter

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import HomeView from "../components/views/public/HomeView";
import LoginView from "../components/views/public/LoginView";
import NotFound from "../components/views/public/NotFound";
import RegisterView from "../components/views/public/RegisterView";

const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        {/* Rutas publicas: */}
        <Route path="/" element={<HomeView />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginView />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterView />} />
        {/* Rutas privadas: */}
        <Route path="dashboard/*" element={<Dashboard />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
export default AppRouter;
```

#### Dashboard

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AccountingHomeView from "../components/views/accounting/AccountingHomeView";
import { EcommerceHomeView } from "../ecommerce/EcommerceHomeView";
import EmployeeHomeView from "../employee/EmployeeHomeView";
import NotFound from "../public/NotFound";
import DashboardHomeView from "./DashboardHomeView";

const Dashboard = function () {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<DashboardHomeView />} />
        <Route path="accounting" element={<AccountingHomeView />} />
        <Route path="employee" element={<EmployeeHomeView />} />
        <Route path="ecommerce" element={<EcommerceHomeView />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Hola, ¿qué servicio de autenticación estás utilizando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola te podría dar una solución a tu problema, en mi caso utilizo el servicio de autenticación de Firebase, y lo que realizo es verificar si el existe un usuario activo, es decir, registrado, si es así, puede acceder a las rutas privadas, por lo contrario los redirige a la página de registro o de inicio.

Por ejemplo en el archivo index.js, tengo todas las rutas:

```
const Index = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
            <Route path="/login-ecpan-admin" component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/ecpan-admin">
                <AdminPanel />
            </PrivateRoute>
         </Switch>
     </BrowserRouter>              
</AuthProvider>
```

);
}

Como puedes ver tengo un componente personalizado llamado "PrivateRoute", y el "AuthProvider" el cual es el proveedor de un estado global llamado "AuthContext", en el cual almaceno el usuario autenticado.

**AuthPovider**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {auth, onAuthStateChanged} from '../firebase/firebaseConfig';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

// This context will be present in Main.jsx and ProvateRoute.jsx 
const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const cancelSuscription = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
            setUser(user)
            setLoading(false)
        });

       return cancelSuscription;
    }, [])

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{user}}>
            {!loading && children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}

export {AuthContext, AuthProvider};
```

Ahora bien, dicha información la utilizaremos en el componente personalizado que mencioné en un inicio ("PrivateRoute") donde encapsularás las rutas privadas.

**PrivateRoute**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router';
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts';

const PrivateRoute = ({children, ...propierties}) => {
    const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);

    if (user) {
        return <Route {...propierties}>{children}</Route>
    } else {
        return <Redirect to="/login-ecpan-admin" />
    }
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Como se puede apreciar éste componente recibe dos propiedades: **children** el cual es la ruta que deseas convertir en privada y **...propierties** el cual es el path. En éste componente utlizamos **redirect** para enviar a una ruta específica dependiendo si el usuario está autenticado o no.

Espero que te sirva mi solución. Si tienes preguntas no dudes en planterlas.

Answer (score 1):

Para la protección de rutas solo basta tener una variable global que determine si existe una sesión activa y compararlo dentro el atributo "element", por ejemplo:

```
export const AppRouter = () => {

    const { usuario } = useContext( AuthContext );
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div  >
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/login" element={ usuario.logged ? (<Navigate to="/"/>): (<LoginScreen />) }/>
                    <Route path="/*" element={ usuario.logged ? (<DashboardRoutes />):( <Navigate to="/login"/>)} />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

Saludos